# Android Activity - Back button not functional when pressed

Tags: android, xml, search, button, back

Pressing the back button inside of an "Android Activity" does not return to the previous page as you would expect.

The activity uses `Searchview.OnQueryTextListener`, and `SearchView.OnCloseListener`. I have searched and seen others with similar issues but none have yielded any solutions yet.

```
public class Scr_Combined_Entry_Hours_Multiple extends VT implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener {
```

In hopes of a solution, an overridden `onBackPressed()` function was added, although this was implemented after the issue occurred and doesn't fix the issue at hand.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.getParent().onBackPressed();   
}
```

Thanks for any help and time given.

Comment: what is 'VT' ? Does that class extend Activity?

Comment: VT Extends activity, this is one of many pages that has the same setup as other pages throughout the system. It also runs perfectly on a different android version, tested version was 4.0.3, functioning version is 4.1.1, this is the only page in the system this occurs.

Comment: Does VT override the back button press? If so, does it call super.onBackPressed()? That might be where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the class is NOT an activity, thus not in the stack and cannot go back down the stack as a result. * Not correct, VT extends Activity *

Comment: VT Extends activity, this is one of many pages that has the same setup as other pages throughout the system. It also runs perfectly on a different android version, tested version was 4.0.3, functioning version is 4.1.1, this is the only page in the system this occurs.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, my mistake